# Error when calling removeEventListener in IE11/Edge on closed window, yet works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, events, dom-events, microsoft-edge, addeventlistener

I created a JSFiddle to showcase the behavior. I've observed IE11/Edge behaves one way and Chrome and Firefox behave another way and I'm not sure which one is of the two cases is a bug or design flaw.

https://jsfiddle.net/vuprp9k9/

HTML:

```
<div id="output">placeholder</div>
<button id="addEvtPopup">Add Event to Pop-up Window</button>
<button id="removeEvtPopup">Remove Event from Pop-up Window</button>
<button id="popupBtn">Open Pop-up Window</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var addEvtPopupBtn = document.getElementById("addEvtPopup");
var removeEvtPopupBtn = document.getElementById("removeEvtPopup");
var popupBtn = document.getElementById("popupBtn");
var popupWin = null;

function myHandler(evt) {
  output.innerHTML = output.myParam;
}

popupBtn.onclick = function() {
  // Observe the variable referencing the pop-up Window
  popupWin = window.open("", "myPopupWin", "width=100px, height=100px, top=500px, left=-1000px");
};

addEvtPopupBtn.onclick = function() { 
  popupWin.addEventListener("unload", myHandler, false);
  output.innerHTML = "Pop-up Event added";
  output.myParam = "Pop-up Event unloaded";
  popupBtn.eventEnabled = true;
};

removeEvtPopupBtn.onclick = function() {
  // Chrome and Firefox: With pop-up closed, popupWin still has reference to closed pop-up window
  // IE11 and Edge: With pop-up closed, popupWin has no reference to closed pop-up window
  // As a result, the next line will error out in the latter browsers but not in the former browsers
  // In both cases, typeof popupWin evaluates to "object"
  popupWin.removeEventListener("unload", myHandler, false);
  output.innerHTML = "Pop-up Event removed";
  popupBtn.eventEnabled = false;
};
```

What's happening here is I open a pop-up window and add an event listener to it. I close the pop-up window and then I remove its event listener.

In Chrome and Firefox, `popupWin.removeEventListener("unload", myHandler, false);` proceeds as normal because even though the pop-up window is closed, `popupWin` still is referencing the pop-up window. With IE11 and Edge, the line throws an error because `popupWin` is not referencing the pop-up window.

**Please understand I'm not looking for an answer of "don't do it that way, do it this way."** I'm trying to understand why Chrome and Firefox still contain a reference to the pop-up window, after it has been closed, while IE11/Edge loses the reference. Which of the two cases are handling the reference to the pop-up window correctly?

**Update**

FYI: The above was tested in a Windows 10 VM with Microsoft Edge version 12.10240. The VM was provided by Microsoft, via their Dev Center.

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/

As such, at least on my end, I have not confirmed that other versions of Edge, i.e. 12.x and 13.x, exhibit this issue of losing the reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a member of the Edge team at Microsoft, this is just a bug on us. I have created an issue internally, and at some point in the (hopefully) not too distant future it will be fixed

Comment: Wow! We have a celebrity in the house. Didn't think anybody at Microsoft would make an appearance on this site ;) In all seriousness, I very much appreciate your response and that you're looking into fixing what is now considered a bug. I gather IE11 will not be updated. I tested it on a Win 10 VM w/Edge 12.10240. The bug also appeared in Edge w/IE11 emulation and I *think* IE10 and IE9 emulation. Will Edge have continuous micro-upgrades and patches, a la Chrome and Firefox, or fixed version releases like Internet Explorer? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: One more thing. I did not test with other Edge 12 versions or Edge 13 versions. As such, I can't confirm on my end if other versions of Edge do not exhibit this problem. Thank you, again.

Comment: haha :]IE 11 will continue to have security updates. Edge was released in november and has already had multiple updates, and will continue to do so

Answer (score 0):

Add the 3rd param may helps.

`.addEventListener("unload", myHandler, true);`

It works on IE11 in my project.

e.g.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function (){ console.log(152) }, true);
```